# Как создать скорректировать оптимизировать аккордеон?

Tags: jquery, инспекция-кода

Создал дословный сценарий:

1. Назначить класс родителям, чтобы добавить оформление знаком
2. Провести проверку на открытые вкладки и закрыть их
3. а) Назначить функции открытия закрытия по клику и смены класса, в зависимости открыты они или закрыты для оформление знаком.
   б) Если вкладка открыта, соседние и их вложения закрываются.

Как правильно его сделать?

[Моя попытка создания на jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/nkpbmew9/8/)

```
$('.multi-accordion li > a').next().parent().addClass('has-children')

$('.multi-accordion li')
    if($(this).parent().children("ul").hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("open").children("ul").slideUp();
    }

$('.multi-accordion .has-children > a').on('click', function (event) { 
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("open")){ 
        $(this).parent().removeClass("open").children("ul").slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("open").children("ul").slideDown();
        $(this).parent().siblings().children("ul").filter(':visible').slideUp();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Стремлюсь разобраться как правильно делать аккордеон с данными функциями на jquery, выявить оптимальный путь и решение. Тем самым помочь всем, кто имеет желание научиться, увидев в ответе хороший пример и его описание.
[Работающий аналог с функциями закрытия-открытия на css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479413/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5/481893?noredirect=1#comment555385_481893)